# SonataUserBundle oneToMany Mapping Error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I dont know what else to try, this seems like it should be so straight forward, but the Symfony profiler continues to show this error:
[image]

Here are my User and Venue classes:

User:

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Venue",    mappedBy="user")
     */
     protected $venues;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->venues = new ArrayCollection();
    }

}
```

Venue:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Venue
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Venue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="venues")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

It seems to work fine in the application, I only get the error inside the Symfony Profiler.  It keeps telling me venues doesnt exist on User but Im looking right at it!  What am I not doing correctly here?

Comment: Are you sure you have mapped your user entity using annotations ?  by default sonata uses xml format for mapping, check doctrine folder under resources folder of your application user bundle

Comment: Yes, this was the issue.  I was under the impression if I just added annotations they'd just work.  :)   I removed the xml config files completely and the annotations now wok without conflict.  Thank you for your response.